# SQL timeout occurs while getting the count after filter/search the dynamically modifed value in the IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, search, iqueryable

In our project we have used the below code to populate the data to a table. While getting the count after filtering or searching the below highlighted "Exceeded" field we are getting the timeout from SQL .
Screenshot attached

```
IQueryable data = _context.Orders;
IQueryable<SelectList> dataSource = (from t in _context.Orders
    select new
    {
        t.OrderID,
        t.CustomerID,
        t.EmployeeID,
        t.ShipCity,
        CustomerName = t.Employees.FirstName,
        EmployeeName = t.Employees.FirstName + " " + t.ShipCity,
        cashier = _context.Orders.Where(c => c.OrderID == t.OrderID).Select(c => c.CustomerID + " " + c.ShipCity)
    }).Select(t => new SelectList()
    {
        CustomerName = t.CustomerName,
        ShipCity = t.ShipCity,
        EmployeeName = t.EmployeeName,
        **Exceeded = t.EmployeeID > 5 ? "Yes" : "No"**
    }).AsQueryable();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simplify query?

Comment: Yes, I get this error only when i use  Exceeded field value like the above code example

Comment: Maybe update question with generated SQL.  But I think, you have to create issue in GitHub.

Comment: Please add the generated SQL, table definitions with indexes, and share a query plan via  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/